# Removing duplicacy in tags

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dao, spring-jdbc

I am using DAO in spring mvc to add tags and retrieving them in database(MySQL). My Dao for retrieving the tags from db is :

```
public List<TagCloud> getAllTags() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tags";

    List<TagCloud> tagcloud = new ArrayList<TagCloud>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows=null;
    try{
     rows= getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Map row : rows) {
        TagCloud tc1 = new TagCloud();

        tc1.setName((String)row.get("name"));
        tc1.setCount((Integer)row.get("count"));
        tc1.setFontSize((Double)row.get("fontsize"));
        tc1.setTagid( (Integer)row.get("tagid")  );

        tagcloud.add(tc1);
    }

    return tagcloud;
}
```

now i already have college as a tag in database, if i add college,course as 1 tag it has to split these words and check for duplicacy.. since college is already added, it has to ignore college, increase count and font and add course to the tag.. how do i do that

Comment: question not clear to me, what are the contents of the table tags

Comment: the attributes in the table are tagid, name, count and fontsize